# Where can I find documentation of RPM macro expansion?

Tags: macros, packaging, rpm, rpm-spec

I'm working with some RPM spec files and `.rpmmacros` which are failing with a newer version or build of RPM than they were intended to be used with, and I'm trying to make sense of them, but I can't find any good documentation on how RPM expands parameterized macros. In particular, I'm unclear whether `%%` inside the macro body, which presumably expands to a single `%`, gets expanded again after the first macro is expanded, or remains as a literal `%` sign. But what I'd really like is some good documentation on the whole RPM macro system, which I'm unfamiliar with (I inherited the mess from somebody else and wouldn't be using RPM by choice at all). Any pointers?

Comment: If you `%define` something, it is re-evaluated each time. If it is `%global` then only once. This might help the `%%` thing.

Answer (score -1):

if you run

```
rpm --showrc
```

you get the value of every macro currently known to rpm.
Among that output, lookout for the line stating with *macrofiles*, it contains a list of every macro file rpm evaluates to get to the values.